# How do I use `np.where()` to compare the arrays not individual values

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an image(2D array) with 3 color channels. Something like this:

```
[[[128 197 254]
  [128 197 254]
  [128 197 254]
  ...
  [182 244 255]
  [182 244 255]
  [182 244 255]]

 [[128 197 254]
  [128 197 254]
  [128 197 254]
  ...
  [182 244 255]
  [182 244 255]
  [182 244 255]]

 [[128 197 254]
  [128 197 254]
  [128 197 254]
  ...
  [182 244 255]
  [182 244 255]
  [182 244 255]]

 ...

 [[128 197 254]
  [128 197 254]
  [128 197 254]
  ...
  [182 244 255]
  [182 244 255]
  [182 244 255]]

 [[128 197 254]
  [128 197 254]
  [128 197 254]
  ...
  [182 244 255]
  [182 244 255]
  [182 244 255]]

 [[128 197 254]
  [128 197 254]
  [128 197 254]
  ...
  [182 244 255]
  [182 244 255]
  [182 244 255]]]
```

I want to get the indexes of the colors that are [255, 255, 255] for example. I tried using `np.where()` or `np.argwhere()`, but it compared values not arrays. What is the fastest and most efficient way to do it?

Comment: How did you try to use `np.where`?

Comment: `where` is only as good as the boolean condition array that you give it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you may use `np.nonzero`

```
np.nonzero((arr==255).all(axis=2))
```

That will return a tuple of arrays, which represent the indexes. If you do

```
arr[ind]
```

where `ind` is the return from the first expr, you may access/modify all rows with all 255.

Answer (score -1):

> A numpy way to do this with np.where would be

```
import numpy as np

# Generating an example array
width = 100 
height = 100
channels = 3
img = np.random.rand(width, height, channels) * 255

# Defining the three value channels
r=0 
g=1 
b=2

# Defining the query values for the channels, here [255, 255, 255]
r_query = 255
g_query = 255
b_query = 255

# Print a 2D array with the coordinates of the white pixels
print(np.where((img[:,:,r] == r_query) & (img[:,:,g] == g_query) & (img[:,:,b] == b_query)))
```

This gives you a 2D-Array with the coordinates of the white pixels [255, 255, 255] in your original array (image).

> *Note:* Another way would be using OpenCV

```
mask = cv2.inRange(img, [255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255])
output = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = mask)
```

Comment: @RafaelC, thanks for the comment and smooth answer (+1). The last entry in my codesnippet refers to the three channels (r, g, b) when sticking to the image analogy.  I guess it depends on the shape of the array. This code works for me without errors and does what was asked.

Comment: Ah ok I see what you did there ;)